# Is Rate Limit Policy Shared Between Mapped Routes in ASP.NET Core

Tags: rate-limiting, .net-7.0

According to this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/rate-limit?view=aspnetcore-7.0

A named policy can be applied to specific routes on Minimal API, if it is applied to multiple routes, is the policy shared between the routes?

For example if the fixed window policy is used, would activating all the routes contribute to the same window limit?